# parsing JS (with functions) using GSON

Tags: javascript, gson

I have a bunch of files containing Javascript, which store configuration metadata, and I'd like to use GSON (2.2.4) to parse them into Java objects to be read by my application.
This works for simple name/value pairs, but if my JS file has a function, of course GSON throws an exception:

```
[
    {
        text:'Cost',
        renderer:function(value)
        { 
           return 0; 
        }   

    },  ...
```

`com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 4 column 38`

I'm wondering if there's any way to have GSON parse this type of JS file, even if it has to completely ignore functions and just parse the simple name/value pairs?
I guess I'd need to do some preprocessing on the input?

Comment: I'm just reading about it, but it's just a JSON library for Java right?  JSON itself doesn't support functions as values to keys.  Does GSON?

Comment: What you posted is not JSON, so why do you think a JSON library should be able to parse this?

Comment: As I said in the question; I am aware that this is Javascript and not JSON.  However, GSON is capable of parsing the attributes - all I need is to disregard the functions as opposed to throwing a parsing error

Comment: The fact that Felix Kling's comment was upvoted, despite ignoring details of the original question, is a discredit to the site

Answer (score 4):

Technically, functions are not a data type which is represented by the JSON format in the [spec](http://www.json.org/), those are rather:

*`string`* *`number`* *`object`* *`array`* **`true`** **`false`** and **`null`**

In practice, a lot of JSON parsers will ignore functions while serializing a JSON object, like the Javascript version [as implemented by many browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description):

> If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

So, I don't know how you are receiving the JSON, but **serializing it correctly is the best solution** and it is usually the easiest, if you can.

**If you don't have control over the JSON** you are receiving, then GSON gives you the possibility of [**defining custom deserializers**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization), which should make you be able to actually parse the JSON you have correctly and without throwing exceptions. But it will require a little amount of work, obviously.